# OpenSSL LNK2019 Errors

Tags: visual-c++, openssl, linker, linker-errors

I'm trying to link OpenSSL with my C++ project in Visual Studio 2019. I get these errors:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _EVP_EncryptUpdate referenced in function _main  Crypter2    C:\Users\jcava\source\repos\Crypter2\Crypter2\encryption.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _ERR_print_errors_fp referenced in function _handleErrors    Crypter2    C:\Users\jcava\source\repos\Crypter2\Crypter2\encryption.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _EVP_aes_128_cbc referenced in function _main    Crypter2    C:\Users\jcava\source\repos\Crypter2\Crypter2\encryption.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new referenced in function _main Crypter2    C:\Users\jcava\source\repos\Crypter2\Crypter2\encryption.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset referenced in function _main   Crypter2    C:\Users\jcava\source\repos\Crypter2\Crypter2\encryption.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _EVP_DecryptInit_ex referenced in function _main Crypter2    C:\Users\jcava\source\repos\Crypter2\Crypter2\encryption.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _EVP_DecryptUpdate referenced in function _main  Crypter2    C:\Users\jcava\source\repos\Crypter2\Crypter2\encryption.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _EVP_EncryptFinal_ex referenced in function _main    Crypter2    C:\Users\jcava\source\repos\Crypter2\Crypter2\encryption.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _EVP_EncryptInit_ex referenced in function _main Crypter2    C:\Users\jcava\source\repos\Crypter2\Crypter2\encryption.obj    1
```

Under VC++ directory I added under include:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL\include";
```

and I added under library directories:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL\lib";
```

Under Linker general I added under additional library directory:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL\lib";
```

My full source code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")


void handleErrors(void){
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  abort();
}

int main(){
  //read in the exe file and convert its bytes to a string
  FILE *inFile;
  inFile = fopen("Quasar.exe","rb");
  if (inFile == NULL){
    perror("Failed to read in file\n");
  }

  printf("File read in complete!\n");

  if(fseek(inFile , 0 , SEEK_END) == -1){
    perror("Offset error\n");
  };
    unsigned long lSize = ftell(inFile);
  if (lSize == -1){
    perror("Size error\n");
  }
    rewind(inFile);

  unsigned char *unencryptedText = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)*lSize);
  if (unencryptedText != NULL) {
      fread(unencryptedText, 1, lSize, inFile);
  }
  else {
      printf("File error");
      exit(0);
  }
  fclose(inFile);

  unsigned char *encryptedText = (unsigned char*) malloc (3 *(sizeof(unsigned char)*lSize));

  //encrypt these bytes with open ssl
  printf("Encrypting...\n");
  int outlen, tmplen;
  unsigned char key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
  unsigned char iv[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
  EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);

  if(EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, encryptedText, &outlen, unencryptedText, lSize *sizeof(char)) == 0){
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    return 0;
  }
      
  if(EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, encryptedText + outlen, &tmplen) == 0){
    ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
    return 0;
  }
  outlen += tmplen;
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
  printf("Encrypt Success!\n");

  char absPath[500];
    strcpy (absPath, "encrypted.dat");
    FILE *outFile = fopen(absPath, "wb");
    if (encryptedText != NULL) {
        fwrite(encryptedText, lSize, 1, outFile);
    }
    else {
        perror("File is null");
    }
    fclose (outFile);


//decrypt the files
unsigned char *decryptedText = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)*lSize);
EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);

if(EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, decryptedText, &outlen, encryptedText, lSize) == 0){
  ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
  return 0;
}

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
printf("Decrypt Success!\n");


return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You've added all the paths to the directories, but not yet included the library for the linker. IOW, you've told the linker where to look, but not told it what it should look for yet. The libraries are libeay.lib and ssleay.lib, IIRC

Comment: The libraries should be added to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`